# How do I wrap argparse options into the python class?

Tags: python, class, parameter-passing, argparse

I am pretty new to python OOP, so I got some confusion.

Currently I have:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='script 1.0')
parser.add_argument('-a', '--foo', help='specify foo')
parser.add_argument('-b', '--bar', type=int, help='specify bar')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--baz', help='specify baz')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--bar2', help='bar2')

args = parser.parse_args()

foo = args.foo
bar = args.bar
baz = args.baz
bar2 = args.bar2
```

which works pretty well, but I wan to create a class for the whole of my script and make argparse as a class's method (is it possible at all?).

So I tried:

```
     import argparse
         ....

        Class Program:
             def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz, bar2):
                 self.foo = foo
                 self.bar = bar
                ...(so on for each arg)
             def main():
                 parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='script 1.0')
                 parser.add_argument('-a', '--foo', help='specify foo')
                 parser.add_argument('-b', '--bar', type=int, help='specify bar')
                 parser.add_argument('-c', '--baz', help='specify baz')
                 parser.add_argument('-d', '--bar2', help='bar2')

                 args = parser.parse_args()

                 foo = self.foo
                 bar = self.bar
                 baz = self.baz
                 bar2 = self.bar2
```

I do not think I am doing right, though. I have not found too much info about it but one post on  SO which did not clarify situation to me, so I want to have opinions for my specific case

Comment: You seem to be on right track, What problem are you actually facing ?

Comment: @ZdaR, argparse options did not get remembered for the further usage, I was about, should not I intianalize class like this:

__init__(self, --foo, --bar, --baz, --bar2)

Comment: I think it's best to have clear separation of concerns.  In other words, separate your CLI input from your business logic (Program Class).  To do this i would only use argparse when your script gets executed directly.  In other words, under the `if __name__ == __main__` section.  then once argparse has done it's work, create a class instance passing the parsed arguments to it, and running your logic.

Comment: Writing good OOP does not mean everything needs to in a class.
It is also important to have your class do a single thing. As stated by the Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 2):

`argparse` is already makes use of classes.  `argparse.ArgumentParser(...)` creates a parser object.  `parser.add_argument(...)` creates an `Action` object, and puts it in a `parser` list.  It also returns it to your code, which may in some advanced uses be handy.  `parse_args()` returns a `argparse.Namespace` object.

You can subclass the `argparse` classes to customize their performance.

But usually you don't need to create your own `parser` class - unless you need a lot of special behavior.

Here's what I'd consider to be a clean use of `argparse`:

```
import argparse

# your code
def main(args):
    foo = args.foo
    # other uses of args

def other(foo, bar):
    # code using values

def make_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='script 1.0')
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--foo', help='specify foo')
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--bar', type=int, help='specify bar')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--baz', help='specify baz')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--bar2', help='bar2')
    return parser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = make_parser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Wrapping the parser definition in a function is a good idea.  In more complex cases it could be a class.  But normally you only need one parser per script, so a function is enough.  That function can be in the main body of the script, but actual use should be in a `if __name__` block, so the script can be imported without using the parser.

This puts the `args` namespace in the global environment, where is accessible to all your code.  It can be passed as to your functions, or selected values can be passed:

```
main(args)
other(args.foo, args.bar)
foo = args.foo
do_things3(foo)
d = vars(args) # args in dictionary form
```

It's a good idea to write your code so it works as imported classes and/or functions, and when run as a script.  The `argparse` part sets values when run as a script.  When imported, the importing script sets the necessary control values, possibly with its own `parser`.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
import argparse


Class Program:
    def __init__(self, foo, bar, baz, bar2):
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = bar
        ...(so on for each arg)
    
    def do_things():
        pass

         
def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='script 1.0')
    parser.add_argument('-a', '--foo', help='specify foo')
    parser.add_argument('-b', '--bar', type=int, help='specify bar')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--baz', help='specify baz')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--bar2', help='bar2')

    return parser.parse_args()


def main(args):
    instance = Program(args.foo,
                       args.bar, 
                       args.baz, 
                       args.bar2)

    instance.do_things()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = get_args()
    main(args)
```

Explanation:
Try to separate things...
Parsing the arguments is done in the `get_args` function, and then pass the "args" to the main.
The `main` function is in charge to initialize the object by the parameters that been passed as `args` and perform some work on the object.